# Can you use powershell 'here string' in a ps shell window or only scripts?

Tags: powershell

I'm just learning powershell and I'm trying to set up a multi-line here string in the shell window, inputing:

```
$hs = @"
```

at this point I hit enter and instead of letting me continue adding to the here string I get the error:

> The string is missing the terminator: "@.
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString

Which makes sense, but I'm sure I've seen examples of here strings that appear to have been constructed at a ps command prompt. Is this doable or are here strings only for scripts?

Comment: What version of powershell? I cannot reproduce this.

Comment: What host are you use? In ISE you need to use `Shift+Enter` to write multiline command.

Comment: `Shift`+`Enter` also works with the console version (although the experience is better if you use the PSReadline module, which will let you edit previous lines).

Answer (score -1):

```
$hs = @'
Test
'@
```

That should work in the console or in a script.

BTW, single quote strings are literal and do not expand variables.  They just literally output the variable name.

Double quote strings are expanding strings and will expand variables (show their value).

You can play around with this.

```
$testVariable = "test variable content"

$stringLiteral = @'
line 1
 line 2
  line 3
   $testVariable
    line 5
'@

$expandingString = @"
line 1
 line 2
  line 3
   $testVariable
    line 5
"@

"String Literal:  "
$stringLiteral 


"Expanding String:  "
$expandingString
```

Comment: This does not attempt to answer the OP's question

Comment: @JacobColvin His post title asks if here strings work in the shell or only in scripts.  How does my reply "That should work in the console or in a script" not answer that question?

Comment: Imagine I post: Command-Name gives me this exception, why? And you answer, "just try using Command-Name". The OP had an issue using multi-line strings and your answer told him "try using a multi-line string". The comments on the post answered the question.

Comment: Tough crowd.  I see this post as multiple questions.  One of which I answered.  The other was already answered in the comments you referred to.